# Selecting Columns: The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, entity, entity-framework-6.1

I need some help with an optimisation of a lambda expression.

**Entities**

```
    public class ProductGroup 
    {

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<GroupProduct> GroupProducts { get; set; }

    }

    public class GroupProduct 
    {

            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            // Foreign Key
            public int ProductGroupId { get; set; }
            public int ProductId { get; set; }

            // Navigation Properties
            [Required]
            [ForeignKey("ProductGroupId")]
            public virtual ProductGroup ProductGroup { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
            public virtual Product Product { get; set; }    
        }

    public class Product
        {

            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [Index(IsUnique = true)]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string Code { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100)]
            public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

**Expression Currently Used**

```
var q = context.ProductGroups.Where(s => s.Code == code)
            .Include(s => s.GroupProduct.Select(p => p.Product));
```

There are a lot more columns in the `Product` Entity. What I'm trying to do optimise the expression so when the SQL is generated on the `Product.Code` column is selected and not the entire `Product` table, along with the Related GroupProduct, and the owning ProductGroup.

When I try and "Filter" the Product entity I get a error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation
>   property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference
>   navigation properties and the Select operator for collection
>   navigation properties. Parameter name: path

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want Product.Code, why not query Product only (with a select of Code of course)